# How can I set different <title> values for each template in ejs?

Tags: sails.js, ejs

I am using Sails.js and it comes with ejs-templates. There is a default view called layout.ejs which is always including the body parts from other templates. The title element is defined in the layout.ejs and is therefore always the same. Due to SEO I would like to change the title depending on the view that is included. Is there some way of knowing which view is actually called from Sails, in the .ejs file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update the `<title>` tag of your `layout.ejs` to

`<title><%= title %></title>`

and send a `title` value from your controller along with the other data, like

`res.view('viewname', { title: 'YourTitle', data: data });`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution works fine, if you set a page title in every controller. Otherwise it will be failing with `title is not defined at eval`. 
I extended this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520452/how-to-use-dynamic-page-titles-in-sails-js-v1-0/